# Jquery - reserve element of the plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to do a simple plugin that uses some functions outside of the this.each method
I would like to use on two elements of the same page but I have problems because it makes reference to the
same table elements.

```
;(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
    'use strict';

    function init() {
        makeHeader.call(this);
        $('<p>footer</p>').insertAfter('table');
    }

    function makeHeader() {
        $('<p>header</p>').insertBefore('table');
    }

    $.fn.MYPlugin = function(options) {
        var options = $.extend(true, {}, defaults, options);

        return this.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);

            init.call(this);

            $this.on('click', 'th', function() {
                alert('Hallo!');
            });

        });
    };
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

js

```
$(function() {
    $('#tbl').MYPlugin();
    $('#tbl2').MYPlugin();
});
```

html

```
<table id="tbl" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<table id="tbl2" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

How can I do so that the plugin only works in the reserved context of the initialized element (#tbl or #tbl2) so you can use it on multiple items on the same page?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You take the trouble to intialize by calling `init.call(this)` but fail to utilize `this` in `init()` other than passing it on to `makeHeader()` ... where it is also not utilized!

Try :

```
function init() {
    makeHeader.call(this);
    $('<p>footer</p>').insertAfter(this);
}

function makeHeader() {
    $('<p>header</p>').insertBefore(this);
}
```

Comment: Your solution is good for me! But if you want to access in my function in the table(this) elements as thead or tr, how am I supposed to do? Thanks!

Comment: In the `.each()` loop, `var $this = $(this)` gives you a reference to a table. You can use jQuery's `.find()`  method to select elements within the table, eg `var $thead = $this.find('thead');`.

Comment: Can I use ('thead', this) instead  of find? thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, `$('thead', this)` will also work. You can use whatever selection method you like.